# Location of star HD 135591

Tags: star

The star is located at a distance of 163,000 light years in the constellation of Circinus.  As the Milky Way is 100,000 light years, this would then imply the star is outside the Milky Way?  Would it be a data anomoly if that is the case or is it in another galaxy like r136a?  Would it be on the far side of the galaxy, other side of the Galactic Centre?

Comment: Where did you get that distance from? A [SIMBAD search](http://simbad.u-strasbg.fr/simbad/sim-id?Ident=HD%20135591%20) says it has a parallax of 0.92±0.29 mas, corresponding to a distance of just over 1.1 kpc, or 3500 lightyears.

Comment: I have found the Wikipedia article which the OP got that distance from (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_stars_in_Circinus). It gives the distance to HD 135591 as 163,000ly without a direct reference, and it hasn't been changed since the page was written in 2007. I agree with you @pela, 3500 light years sounds much more reasonable for a H. Draper catalogue star!

Comment: Well, just shows that answers or questions that *rely* on Wikipedia for their information may not be reliable...

Comment: Using Hip.dat from Simbad, I got 163,081.70

Comment: That's taken from the old Hipparcos catalogue from [1997](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-S?HIP%20%2074941), it appears that the parallax was increased from 0.02 to 0.92 mas when the new reduction was performed in [2007](http://cds.aanda.org/articles/aa/pdf/2007/41/aa8357-07.pdf) by van. Leeuwen

Comment: ok, Dean, thanks for the information, managed to track down Hip2 at http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/ftp-index?/ftp/cats/aliases/H/HIP2

Comment: Using the figures from Hip2, i managed to get 3500 but when I applied it to Chi Aurigae, the calculation went awry, it calculated it as being 326,163.  :(

Comment: I see the wiki page was updated/corrected on the day this question went out.